# Dataframe Element to Tkinter Widgets (not pandastable)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tkinter, vectorization

I have a pandas Dataframe that is extracted from a file, the Dataframe will not have the same size each time, it depends on the file.
I want to create a couple tkinter labels and an entry widget for every row in this Dataframe but without using a for loop since the size changes. I also want to be able to update the Dataframe with the info from the entry field.
Here's an example of the Dataframe:

```
data = {'Name'       :['W DEL 69', 'ROSE GN1', 'ROSE GN2', 'DANSK G4', 'DANSK G3'],
        'ID'         :['1', '1', '2', '4', '3'],
        'Bus Number' :[125142,125190,125192,125193,125194],
        'Status'     :[1,1,1,1,1],
        'PGEN'       :[4.28,534.7,549.17,210.69,114.23],
        'PMIN'       :[0.0,150.0,0.0,90.0,60.0],
        'PMAX'       :[7.5,599.0,617.0,225.0,139.0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Obviously, I can find the size of the Dataframe and use a for loop, that seems to be the only answer I've found. However, the size can get pretty big and I know looping through a Dataframe is frowned upon if you want the code to be efficient and fast.
Using the info from this [video](https://youtu.be/HN5d490_KKk), I'm wondering if there's a way to achieve this using df.apply or Numpy. Any insight?

(ps: not looking to display full Dataframe)

the only way I can kind of achieve what I want is with this:

```
df    = df.set_index('Name')
index = df.index
for t in index:

    name = t+'_label'                   #make a str with name of bus+ "label" to use as a variable 

    locals()[name]= tk.Label(window,text=t)  #create a label using the name 
    locals()[name].grid(column=c, row=r, padx=2)
```

The reason why this isn't a desired methodology is that I need two labels one entry field per bus, I need to save the entry field for further analysis and most importantly the DataFrame is extracted and will be much larger than the example I gave.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If your data starts as a dict then make a for loop with the dict. If not (and I have no idea if this would work.. But would be cool if it does) what if you did something along the lines of: df[button'] = Tk.button(data you need). You could then use df['button'].tolist() to get a list of those elements?